# Facebook api permission

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

For a couple of website I have a facebook integration with the current JS library. Logging in works as expected.

I use the Facebook C# api with the JS library (v6). When a Facebook user is succesfully authenticated through the JS call it will send an ajax call to a C# method:

```
FacebookClient facebookClient = new FacebookClient(accessToken);

var fbResult = facebookClient.Get("me");
if (fbResult.GetType().ToString() != "Facebook.JsonObject")
     return null;

IDictionary<String, Object> result = (IDictionary<String, Object>)fbResult;

if (result.ContainsKey("email"))
    email = (String)result["email"];
            else
throw new Exception("E-mail key not found")
```

Now this works fine, the accessToken is passed, used by the c# library to get the user's information.

But for about 1 in 100 users the Exception is thrown! For some reason the e-mail key is not included in the "api".

On developers.facebook.com I have setup my app in "Auth Dialog" to "Authenticated Referrals": email and user_birthday.

But how is this possible? Am I overlooking something? How come the user can login to my app without the correct permissions?

Comment: Have you tried to output the response you get to the logs when this occurs? Maybe the response is an exception from facebook for example?

Comment: Yes I did, but the exception is very specific, just the e-mail key is missing. There is lots of logging now in it. I cannot get to do this behavior myself and neither anyone I know. There must be some hidden feature somewhere to remove your e-mail from the app.

Comment: You can use the [explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) to remove the permissions you now have (DELETE to `me/permissions`) and then re-add all permissions but without the "email" one. That will let you create a similar scenario for testing purposes.

Comment: Thanks, very handy tool! But it doesn't explain why this behavior occurs..

Comment: You're right. Have you checked a user for which you got this exception, what happens if you try to get his data on another time? Does the response get back the same?